# Jquery add class for special character id

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I have a id with special characters like,

```
var aaa = "someCompany=&#034;some's Data&#034;";
aaa = aaa.replace(/&#034;/gi, "\"").replace(/&#039;/gi, "\'").replace(/&amp;/gi, "\&");
var abc = aaa.replace(/\"/gi, "\\\"").replace(/\:/gi, "\:").replace(/\'/gi,"\\\'");
var abcId = "li[id=\"" + abc + "\"]";
$(abcId).addClass(" sel");
```

In IE not able to "addClass" for "abcId" but working fine in firefox.

Could anyone please tell me how to handle these special characters...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there an error in IE?

Comment: The better solution is to slugify the id.

Comment: Error in IE is: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Having special characters in the id:s seems like asking for trouble. I would recommend that you strip out or replace any special characters.

Comment: if I strip out all special characters then when i alert for $(abcId).html() is giving null

Comment: It may be helpful to output and compare what IE returns for abcId to what Firefox/etc. returns for abcId. i.e. $('<div>').text(abcId).appendTo('body');

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but you might think about doing something cheap like URL encoding the id as it's written. Then you can use `$('#' + escape(theID))` to get it with JQuery. After that you can add your class with `$('#' + escape(theID)).addClass("sel")`

To clarify further, you'd write out your HTML with the ID URL Encoded like this: (Most server technologies can do this with a simple method call)

```
<div id="someCompany%3D%26%23034%3Bsome's+Data%26%23034%3B">Content here.</div>
```

Then your javascript would be like this:

```
$('#' + escape("someCompany=&#034;some's Data&#034;")).addClass("sel")
```

Comment: Yes, there are some libraries for this like http://urldecoderonline.com/javascript-url-decode-jquery-plugin.htm

Comment: Also note that in the original example, the class string is " sel", with a leading space.

Comment: @dgvid: That won't do anything. It was a mistake or a typo. It'll just add a reference to class "sel" with a superfluous space.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
$(abc).addClass("sel");
```

If you have the ID of the li, why are you using a selector?

Comment: Also try alert(abc) to make sure the value is correct and the problem isn't occurring elsewhere.

Comment: well, my li tag is not having Id, so creating it with abcId

Comment: Yes, there should be only one element named with a particular ID, so if the html complies with that, it should be no problem.

Comment: Max, if the li element you wish to select does not have an id equal to abc, then you won't be able to select it.

Comment: @Theofanis, something about your $(abc) answer: I think it would be most appropriately $("#" + abc) since abc is a string and the # character tells jQuery to look for the element with an id of abc. $(abc) would look for a tag named for the value of abc, as in <valueOfAbc /> instead of <li id="valueOfAbc"></li>